# inline javascript alert on enter keypress using inline coding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to alert 1 on enter keypress can anyone help me to solve this? i am doing this inline because to work in rows and on every time enter key press send a row num with that request

```
      <input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" onkeydown="javascript: if (keyCode == 13) alert(1)"/>
```

Comment: You need to use the Event interface (first parameter or `window.event`).

Comment: This could be accomplished without it being inline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use inline js, just put event.keycode instead of keycode you can use:

```
<input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" onkeydown="javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13) alert(1);"/>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. you got my question.

Comment: It helped me to fix with my current issue, I have used onkeypress and onclick both for keyboard and mouse event release.

Answer (score 5):

why inline?? when you can call event in jquery

try this

```
$('#tt').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    {
      alert(1);
    }
}
```

and if incase you need inline... you need to call `event.keyCode` to get the keycode of key pressed

```
 <input..name="tt" onkeydown="yourFuncName(event)"....>

 function yourFuncName(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13) 
     {
        alert(1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Because there are weird situations in HTML5 gaming frameworks for one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" onkeydown="myFunction(event)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(e) {
        if (e.which === 13 || e.charCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 13)
            alert(1);
    }
</script>
```

Please not that not all browsers support `keyCode`. Some use `which` and others use `charCode`.